# My ouput for C differs from compiler to compiler

Tags: c

I am writing a function longestStrInAr() that takes in an array of strings str and size (>0) as parameters, and returns the longest string and also the length of the longest string.

If two or more strings have the same longest string length, then the first appeared string will be
returned to the calling function.

This is the main function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 20
char *longestStrInAr(char str[N][40], int size, int *length);
int main()
{
   int i, size, length;
   char str[N][40], first[40], last[40], *p, *result;
   char dummychar;
   
   printf("Enter array size: \n");
   scanf("%d", &size);
   scanf("%c", &dummychar);
   for (i=0; i<size; i++) {
      printf("Enter string %d: \n", i+1);
      fgets(str[i], 40, stdin);
      if (p=strchr(str[i],'\n')) *p = '\0';
   }
   result = longestStrInAr(str, size, &length);
   printf("longest: %s \nlength: %d\n", result, length);
   return 0;
}
```

This is the function I have to write:

```
char *longestStrInAr(char str[N][40], int size, int *length)
{
    int i,j, len;
    *length =0;
    char *longstr;
    for (i = 0; i< size; i++){
        j = 0;
        len = 0;
        while (str[i][j]!='\0'){
               len++;
               j++;
                    if (len > *length){
                        *length = len;
                        longstr = str[i];
                    }
        }

    }
    return longstr;
}
```

My test input is

```
Enter array size:
4
Enter string 1:
Kenny
Enter string 2:
Mary
Enter string 3:
Peter
Enter string 4:
Sun
```

In XCode, I am able to receive the correct output:

```
longest: Kenny
length: 5
```

But using 2 different online compilers, I get the output below on both occasions:

```
longest: Kenny
length: 6
```

Why does my length differ?
Thank you.

Comment: Print the ascii codes of each char it finds Then you will know what the 5 and 6 characters are.

Comment: This shows 5. *shrug* https://ideone.com/6oUPsa

Comment: if the outputs differ between compilers or debug/release mode or optimization level... then it's highly likely you're having undefined behavior. **Always turn on all warnings** and read them. That'll help you solve a lot of issues. See https://godbolt.org/z/9vK169

Answer (score 3, accepted):

probably one of them is a windows based compiler.

there `"\n"` is tread as two characters `\r` and `\n`

`\r` is called as carriage return

`\n` is called as line feed.

with this you get a byte extra there.

Comment: Sounds likely, yes. In which case the fix is `str[i][j]!='\0' && !isspace(str[i][j])`. Maybe make a special case to allow `' '`.

Comment: yes looks so.., consider only actual chars not spaces

Comment: the compiler has nothing to do with new lines. It's the C runtime that converts between the system new line (`\r\n`, `\r`, `\n`) and `\n`